# C Struct pointer as Parameter

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, struct, arguments

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a struct in C but i cannot:

```
float calcular_media(struct aluno *aluno) {
```

Output warning:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c gcc main.c aluno.c
aluno.c:7:29: warning: 'struct aluno' declared inside parameter list
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: You will need to post more code.

Comment: The compiler error says it all: the struct is not defined prior to the function definition.

Answer (score 6):

In the file containing the line

```
float calcular_media(struct aluno *aluno) {
```

one of the following must be there before the line

- struct **declaration**: e.g. `struct aluno;` or
- struct **definition**: e.g. `struct aluno { char c; int i; double d; };` or
- ## **include** of some header file which has one of the above: e.g. `#include "aluno.h"`

Answer (score 5):

Are you declaring struct aluno prior to this function?

Either with a full definition:

```
struct aluno {
   ...
};
```

Or at least a forward declaration:

```
struct aluno;
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you will end up doing something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct aluno
{
  int nota1;
  int nota2;
}

float calcular_media(struct aluno* individuo) 
{
  printf("nota 1:%d\n", individuo->nota1);
  printf("nota 2:%d\n", individuo->nota2);
}

int main()
{
  struct aluno primeiro_aluno;
  primeiro_aluno.nota1 = 9;
  primeiro_aluno.nota2 = 5;

  calcular_media(&primeiro_aluno);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the compiler know that there is a struct called aluno before you start passing it to functions.

```
struct aluno {
   int x;
   int y;
};

float calcular_media(struct aluno * aluno) {
       // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a file named "aluno.h" (with the definition of `struct aluno`) and are you including it in "aluno.c"?

```
/* aluno.c */
#include "aluno.h"

float calcular_media(struct aluno *aluno) { /* ... */ }
```